# Why oscillation frequency is not dependent on displacement/amplitude?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, frequency, spring

I'm trying to understand the following question:

The force generated by a spring of spring constant $k$ is $F = -kx$, where $x$ is the displacement from equilibrium. A cube of mass $m$ and length $L$ is attached to the spring, and oscillates around the equilibrium point.

[image]

I'm trying to determine which variables effect the frequency. From what I found it is dependent on $k$ and $m$ only. Why is that? I expected it to be effected from $x$. Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you expect that? Have you solved the equation and actually found the frequency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pull on the cube so that it is a larger distance from the equilibrium point, the spring exerts a larger force on the cube. So, when you let go, the cube will accelerate faster due to the larger force. The cube will be moving faster than a cube with a smaller displacement, so it can cover a longer distance in the same time. For a force like a spring ($F = -kx$), the longer distance and greater acceleration offset each other, so the period of oscillation is the same.

Comment: But the OP wants to know what affects the frequency? Wouldn’t it be changing either K or M?

Answer (score 1):

Remember this is an idealized system. In practice, the spring constant $k$ will depend on $x$ for large $x$--validating your concerns. In the idealized case, consider dimensional analysis. You have 2 parameters with dimensions (M, mass; L, length; T, time):

$k \rightarrow $ Netwon/meter $\rightarrow \frac{\mathrm{ML/T^2}}
{\mathrm  L} = \frac{\mathrm M}{\mathrm T^2}$

and

$M \rightarrow {\mathrm M}$,

so that:

$\sqrt{\frac{k}{M}} \rightarrow \frac{1}{\mathrm T}$,

which is a frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mark's intuitive answer, I want to point out that this is a special property of a restoring force that is linear in the displacement. This is quite special and important in many areas of physics, so this special case gets its own name: (simple) harmonic motion.

In general, one may include higher-order corrections to the restoring force, e.g. cubic: $F=-kx-cx^3$. The additional terms are called anharmonicities and in that case, the resonant frequency *does* depend on the amplitude.

Answer (score 1):

Because the frequency is defined as the number of oscillations(go and back) per second and that is not dependent on diplacement.